# signing up with Google acount using Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

Am trying to use Google OAuth 2.0 authentication strategy to signing up, after i followed all the process the google login page is not coming up and there is no error in my console and the keys are well imported what is the course.
Am making use of react js  and Nodejs as the backend (i dont want use the react Google OAuth 2.0 component) i want every thing at the backend .

My developer console details

Authorised JavaScript origins
URIs :http://localhost:5000

Authorised redirect URIs
URIs:http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback
index.js-file

```
const passport=require('passport')
const User=require("../mongodb/schema/userSchema")
const googleStrategy=require("./googleStrategy")
const signUpStrategy=require("./signUpStrategy")
const loginStrategy=require("./loginStrategy")

passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>done(null,user.id))
passport.deserializeUser((id,done)=>{
    User.findById(id,(err,user)=>{
        if(err){return done(err)}
        done(null,user)
    })
    //return done(null,getUserById(id))
})


passport.use("local-signUp",signUpStrategy)
passport.use("local-login",loginStrategy)
passport.use("google-signUp",googleStrategy)


module.exports=passport
```

googleStrategy.js-file

```
//const  GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
const GoogleStrategy = require( 'passport-google-oauth2' ).Strategy;
const keys = require("./keys")

/*
console.log( keys.GOOGLE.clientID)
console.log( keys.GOOGLE.clientSecret)
*/

//http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback
//   proxy: true
const googleLocalStrategy=new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.GOOGLE.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.GOOGLE.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback   : true,
    proxy: true
 
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
     console.log(profile)
     console.log(token)
     console.log(tokenSecret)
     console.log("tokenSecret")
     return done(err, profile);
  }
)



module.exports=googleLocalStrategy;
```

account.js-file

```
router.get("/auth/google",passport.authenticate("google-signUp",{
    scope:  [ 'email', 'profile' ]
}))

router.get("/auth/google/callback",(req, res, next)=>{
    passport.authenticate("google-signUp",(err, user, info) =>{
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({express:err})
        }
       
            return res.status(200).json({express:user})
    
    })(req, res, next)
})
```

login.js-file from reactjs

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import {useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


function Login(){
    const history=useHistory()
    const [eventInfo,setEventInfo]=useState({password:'',email:''});
    const  {password,email}=eventInfo
    const [error,setError]=useState('')

    const handleChange=(event)=>{
        const {name,value}=event.target
        setEventInfo({...eventInfo,[name]:value})
    }
    const googleSignUp=async ()=>{
        const res=await axios.get('/auth/google',{
        }).then((res)=>{
       
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
           // console.log(error.response.data.express)
           
        })
    }
    const onSubmit=async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData=new FormData();
        formData.append('password',password);
        formData.append('email',email);
        try{
            const res=await axios.post('/login',formData,{
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }).then((res)=>{
                history.push("/home/"+res.data.express.id)
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error.response.data.express)
                //setError(error.response.data.express)
            })

            const{home}=res.data          
            history.push(home)
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }



    return(
        <div>
              {error?error:""}
            <form  onSubmit={onSubmit}  encType="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
            <input type="email" placeholder="name@.com" name="email" onChange={handleChange} required></input>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="passWord ..." name="password" onChange={handleChange} required></input>
            </div>
            <button>login</button> 
            </form>
            <a href="/auth/google" onClick={()=>{googleSignUp()}}>google</a>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: Are you facing any specific issue with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The code use not working because i need to access the back end sever local host to be able to use the google route, rather than the react so what i did was to introduce a button that had a function when you click it the function changes the react local host to the back end local host and also slashing into the require route(google route).